# Why dont arrow functions dont work in IE?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following in IE and it doesnt work but does in chrome and edge

$scope.consList.some(element => element.Key.includes('Dev')))

How can i make this work in IE without breaking in the other browsers

Comment: Because IE doesn't support arrow functions. As well as almost everything from ES6. And nothing of ES7+. Either only write ES5 compliant code or transpile your code for IE.

Comment: Or abandon IE. :) Nobody should be using it anyway.

Comment: I agree abandon , but come people just wont for some reason.

Comment: @Ivar actually my preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support arrow functions. They're in ES6, and IE is stuck mostly in ES5. You'll have to use functions:

```
$scope.consList.some(function(element) { return element.Key.includes('Dev'); });
```

Comment: that wont work because you will get a string and the object doesnt support a property or method 'includes'    should it be   $scope.consList.some(function(element) { return element.Key == 'Dev'; });    ?

Comment: That appears to be a different issue.

Comment: $scope.consList= [];     thats the definition of the array